# Can this formula be added to a WHERE Clause?

Tags: sql, oracle, case, decode, where-clause

I'm a noob to SQL and I'm tasked with converting oracle reports over to ssrs. In the oracle report, there is a general query and then some formulas that are ran to sort the data correctly. Is there a way to put this into the query in the WHERE clause?

***Here is formula that sorts the data I need to combine into a query. Was thinking of a DECODE or CASE statement. Not sure if that would work:***

```
function CF_Steel_FamilyFormula return Char is

v_steel_Family varchar2(20);

begin

  if (:PCT_CA_MIN >=.0001) then
    v_steel_family := 'High Calcium';

  elsif (:PCT_CA_MAX < .0001 and :PCT_MN_MIN >= 1.20) then
    v_steel_family := 'High Manganese';

  elsif (:PCT_MN_MIN >= .80 and :PCT_MN_MIN < 1.20) then
    v_steel_family := 'Medium Manganese';

  elsif (:PCT_MN_MIN <.80 and :PCT_C_MAX <=.01) THEN
    v_steel_family := 'ULC Low Mn';

  elsif (:PCT_C_MAX > .01) then
    v_steel_family := 'LCAK LOW MN';

  else v_steel_family := null;

  end if;

  return v_steel_family;
```

***Here is the general query where I want to combine the above code into:***

```
SELECT

 tg.id_grade
,tg.id_grade sort_grade
,tpi.pk_grade S
,tpi.pk_plant_instruct
,tpi.val_version
,tpi.cde_status
,tpi.tmstp_activated
,tg.pct_ca_min
,tg.pct_ca_max
,tg.pct_mn_min
,tg.pct_c_max

 FROM 
axz0001.txz_plant_instruct@grade_trans.psc.uss.com tpi  
 ,axz0001.txz_grade@grade_trans.psc.uss.com tg

 WHERE tg.pk_grade = tpi.pk_grade   
   AND tpi.id_plant = '161'     
   AND tpi.cde_status = 'D'
   AND tpi.ind_plant_melt = 'Y'


 ORDER BY 

 tg.id_grade
```

Comment: Do you need this formula output in order by clause of oracle query?

Answer (score 2):

You can use it in `WHERE` using `case when` as following:

```
WHERE ...
...
...
AND YOUR_COMPARISION_COLUMN = 
CASE WHEN PCT_CA_MIN > 0.0001
    THEN 'High Calcium'
WHEN PCT_CM_MIN >= 1.2 AND PCT_CA_MAX < 0.0001 
    THEN 'High Manganese'
..
..
WHEN PCT_C_MAX > 0.01 
    THEN 'LCAK LOW MN'
END
```

Hope, this is what you required.

Comment: It does work, however it doesn't perform what I need it to. I suppose I should've worded my question better. Adding what you wrote returns the data ordered by High Calcium, High Manganese, etc.. but it also returns data outside of those fields. 

That's why I was hoping to add something to the WHERE clause if possible

I need this query to only return what qualifies as 'High Calcium', 'High Manganese', LCAK Low Mn' etc..

Comment: Updated my answer now. I have no idea with which column you wanted comparision so putcolumn name accordingly

Comment: Thank you very much